# Does "mount /mnt/mountpoint" in a script use the settings for that mountpoint that are in fstab?

Tags: linux, mount

I have a backup system that uses mounts that are put in place in fstab. I had a failure today because the mount was not there. I want to have my script check for the mount, then mount if it is not present. 
i.e.

```
if mountpoint -q /mnt/mountpoint; then                                                                                                                          
   echo "`date` /mnt/mountpoint is a mountpoint"                                                                                                               
else                                                                                                                                               
   mount /mnt/mountpoint                                                                                                                      
fi
```

Given the above, will `mount` use the settings that are in fstab, or do I need to specify them in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `mount` with one argument (which can be either a directory or a device) uses settings from `/etc/fstab` (at least it is so on Linux).

Alternatively, you can ignore `/etc/fstab` settings and specify both device and mount point explicitly: `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mountpoint`.